# Alcatel 4400 PABX connection with C#

Tags: c#, pabx

I have an Alcatel 4400 PABX.
I would like to know if it is possible to connect with c# and retreive informations on users phone number ?

Can you help me please.

Many thanks

Comment: Does it have an IP interface, Serial, what? Have you tried looking for API or Programming information for this PABX?

Comment: You're either going to need to provide a lot more details about the device in question, or wait *very* patiently until someone comes along that just happens to have the exact same device.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure about Alcatel, but I've worked with another PABX system's API which just implemented the TSAPI (Telephony Services API - I think...) standard.

If it has an IP interface, you will probably just need to get hold of an SDK from that manufacturer.  Most provide .Net libraries, otherwise you might have to interface with an unmanaged library (native DLL) using .Net's platform invoke (pinvoke).

FYI - Ive done this with an Avaya system using the Avaya implementation of the TSAPI.

Comment: Are you referring to their Moagent32.dll, or is there another dll to use? We've been trying to get this information from Avaya for the last month but it seems even they don't know...

Answer (score 2):

You can get to a PABX switch using the TAPI library, which is COM but works with .Net's interop stuff. I'd use C#4 or switch to VB.Net for it, as there are a lot of optional parameters and they're a bit horrid in C# pre its support for them (added in 4).

A much bigger problem is that the TAPI was deprecated in Vista. I guess that sort of makes sense - when did you last buy a PC with a modem?

Depending on Alcatel's support you may still be able to use TAPI on the newer Windows.

Windows Vista and 7 use Microsoft's new RTC (Real Time Communications) framework instead - I'm afraid I don't know it very well (my dialler developing days are 6 years ago now) but it would be the place to start.

I think RTC has now become part of Microsoft Lync ('cause y'know, they need another 'link' style product name with weird misspellings). So Lync's another place to look.